# Why windows 10 ping [hostname] failed?

Tags: windows-10, ping, hostname

I have two Win10 PC with the hostname "PC01" and "PC02"

I have been able to **ping PC01** and **ping PC02** without any problem, until yesterday.

It suddenly hangs. I can ping the PC using IP address though.

May I know what had gone wrong? I have restarted both my router and PC. With no help.

Comment: Provide the hosts file for each machine.  Edit your question instead of submitting a temporary comment

Comment: Probably a DNS issue, run `ipconfig /flushdns` on both machines and try again.

Comment: Ramhound, both hosts file are default, never change anything. I can't ping with any hostsname now. But I can still ping using DNS name, example ping www.google.com works.

Comment: ipconfig /flushdns hangs at "Windows IP Configuration". I have searched in google and none of the solution works